# Load a different JavaScript file according to language

Tags: javascript, php, url

I'm trying to add a cookie banner to my website and it has two different languages: Italian and English.

Language goes as

http://www.grcparfum.it/home.php?section=letteradelpresidente&lang=eng

and

http://www.grcparfum.it/home.php?section=letteradelpresidente&lang=ita

and this is my code:

```
<?php
   $currentlang= $_GET['link'];
   if($currentlang !=eng){
    ?>   
    <script src="/js/cookiechoices-en.js"></script>

   }
<?php else: ?>{
<script src="/js/cookiechoices-it.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
   }
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems you're probably encountering:**

- Some curly brackets are outside of the scope of PHP
- It looks like you should be using `==` for the first `if` statement not `!=`.
- You're trying to compare a constant called `eng` with `$currentlang` rather than `"eng"`

**Try:**

```
<?php
   $currentlang = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // Safer
   if($currentlang == "eng"){ ?>   
        <script src="/js/cookiechoices-en.js"></script>
    <?php } else { ?>{
        <script src="/js/cookiechoices-it.js"></script>
    <?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's never picking the `eng` option.

I think your bug is not putting `eng` in quotes:

```
if($currentlang !=eng){
```

Should be

```
 if($currentlang != "eng"){
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this using JQuery:

```js
url = 'http://www.grcparfum.it/home.php?section=letteradelpresidente&lang=eng';

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
  // results = regex.exec(location.search); gets the url of current window

    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var language = getParameterByName('lang');
english = '<script src="/js/cookiechoices-en.js"><\/script>';
italian = '<script src="/js/cookiechoices-it.js"><\/script>';
if(language == 'eng'){
    $('#script').html(english);
}else if(language == 'ita'){
    $('#script').html(italian);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="script"></div>
```